# Как отменить сортировку JSON файла

Tags: python, json

Предположим у меня есть некоторый словарь, который задает такую структуру в программе:

```
{  
   "B": {
            "K1": 1,
            "K2": 2
        },

   "A": {
            "K3": "QWERTY"
        }
}
```

Вот код программы:

```
data_gen = {
  "B": 
   {
     "K1": lambda : randint(0,5), 
     "K2": lambda : randint(1, 20)}}
   },
  "A":
   {
     "K3": lambda: choice(["QWERTY", "ASDFGHJ"])
   }
}
```

Затем я записываю это все в новый словарь `New_Data` и записываю это в JSON файл:

```
New_Data = {}

for key0 in data_gen:
    for key1 in data_gen[key0]:
        New_Data.setdefault(key0, {})[key1] =  data_gen[key0][key1]()
tmp = Path('newtestnew.json')
tmp.write_text(json.dumps(New_Data,sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': ')), encoding='utf-8')
```

Проблема в том, что в JSON файл это все запишется не так, как мне надо: структуры B и A будут поменяны местами.
Мне нужно, чтобы было так:

```
{  
    "B": {
        "K1": 1,
        "K2": 2
    },

    "A": {
        "K3": "QWERTY"
    }
}
```

А по факту получается так:

```
{  
    "A": {
        "K3": "QWERTY"
    },
    "B": {
        "K1": 1,
        "K2": 2
    }
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы порядок структур в файле при записи не менялся?

Comment: Никак. Порядок объектов в JSON не определён. Этот порядок там и не нужен, ведь к значениям обращаются по ключам, а не по индексам.

Comment: все равно не понятно, почему тогда сортировка идет?
как ее отменить?

Comment: Её нельзя никак отменить. Вам никто не гарантирует при работе с JSON, что сохранится порядок объектов. Он будет зависеть только от внутренней реализации библиотеки для обработки JSON. Вы можете самостоятельно обрабатывать JSON как строку, делая то, что вам удобно. Но, в этом случае, непонятно, зачем вам вообще нужен JSON.

Comment: У вас еще параметр передается `sort_keys=True`

Answer (score 3):

Стоит различать данные, записанные на диск в json формате, и Питон-словари в памяти во время исполнения программы. Как json-объекты так и Питон-словари не упорядочены (dict до Python 3.7).

Чтобы сохранить порядок, можно [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) использовать.

Чтобы прочитать json-файл, сохраняя порядок:

```
import json
from collection import OrderedDict

with open('input.json', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    data = json.load(file, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
```

Чтобы сохранить порядок при записи, достаточно упорядоченную структуру для правил генерации использовать (список для правил, OrderedDict для словарей):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json
import random
from collections import OrderedDict
from functools import reduce

rules = [
    (('B', 'K1'), lambda: random.randint(0, 5)), 
    (('B', 'K2'), lambda: random.randint(1, 20)),
    (('A', 'K3'), lambda: random.choice(["QWERTY", "ASDFGHJ"]))
]

result = OrderedDict()
for (*keys, newkey), generate in rules:
    d = reduce(lambda d, k: d.setdefault(k, OrderedDict()), keys, result)
    d[newkey] = generate()

with open('output.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    json.dump(result, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

#### [Результат](https://ideone.com/LZYTqF)

```
{
    "B": {
        "K1": 5,
        "K2": 2
    },
    "A": {
        "K3": "QWERTY"
    }
}
```

```html
<script  src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/brython-dev/brython/3.4.0/www/src/brython.js"></script><script  src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/brython-dev/brython/3.4.0/www/src/brython_stdlib.js"></script><body onload="brython()"><script type="text/python">
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json
import random
from collections import OrderedDict
from functools import reduce

rules = [
    (('B', 'K1'), lambda: random.randint(0, 5)), 
    (('B', 'K2'), lambda: random.randint(1, 20)),
    (('A', 'K3'), lambda: random.choice(["QWERTY", "ASDFGHJ"]))
]

result = OrderedDict()
for (*keys, newkey), generate in rules:
    d = reduce(lambda d, k: d.setdefault(k, OrderedDict()), keys, result)
    d[newkey] = generate()

print(json.dumps(result))
</script></body>
```

- [Items in JSON object are out of order using "json.dumps"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10844064/4279)
- [Change values in dict of nested dicts using items in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11918852/4279)