# связь двух json файлов: код не входит в if firstValue[key]==KEY ветку

Tags: python, json

у меня есть два json файла, Data.json и Library.json;
Data.json имеет вид

```
{
   "First": 
    {
       "K1": 0, 
       "K2": [1,1,1,1],
       "K3": "QWERTY"
    },
   "Second":
    {
       "K4": 2
    }
}
```

файл Data.json состоит из двух структур: First и Second. У каждой структуры есть поля: K1- константа, K2- список, K3- строка, K4- значение из диапазона.
Library.json имеет вид

```
 {
    "K1": "AAA",
    "K2": "BBB",
    "K3": "CCC",
    "K4": "DDD" 
 }
```

Это, своего рода, библиотека допустимых значений полей, для файла Data.json;
Например, мне нужно, чтобы программа брала поле K4 в файле Data.json, находила его в файле Library.json, видела в этом файле, что K4- это строка "DDD" и создавала новый файл, повторяющий структуру файла Data.json, но уже вместо значения 2, в поле K4, там будет "DDD",из файле Library.json; и так для каждого поля: ,берет К1, ищет его в файле Library, видит строку "AAA" и записывает это в место старого значения. Должно быть что-то вроде этого

```
 {
   "First": 
    {
       "K1": "AAA",
       "K2": "BBB",
       "K3": "CCC"
    },
   "Second":
    {
       "K4": "DDD"
    ;
 }
```

Ниже приведен код программы, я открываю два файла, и делаю поиск ключа из файла Data.json в файле Library.json

```
path = Path('Data.json')
P=Path('Library.json')
data = json.loads(path.read_text(encoding='utf-8'))
library=json.loads(P.read_text(encoding='utf-8'))
for KEY, VALUE in library.items():
    for firstKey, firstValue in data.items():
        for key, value in firstValue.items():
            if(firstValue[key]==KEY):
                firstValue[key]=VALUE
                data[firstKey] = firstValue
tmp = Path('newtestnew.json')
tmp.write_text(json.dumps(data,sort_keys=False, indent=4, separators=(',', ': ')), encoding='utf-8')
```

но моя программа даже не входит в условие, я не знаю почему?

```
 if(firstValue[key]==KEY):
        firstValue[key]=VALUE
        data[firstKey] = firstValue
```

Comment: да вроде все понятно, спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Одна из ошибок: вместо `firstValue[key]==KEY` вы вероятно хотели `key == KEY` написать.

Если   у вас возникают сложности с тем чтобы различить ключ словаря и как по ключу достать значение из словаря, то откройте Питон REPL (наберите python в командной строчке) и поиграйтесь со словарями, чтобы привыкнуть (создайте тестовый словарь, зная ключ, получите значение из словаря, узнайте содержит ли словарь указанный ключ, присвойте новое значение по ключу, итд).

В целом, показанный цикл неэффективен и избыточен.

Неэффективный потому что, чтобы узнать есть ли ключ в словаре вовсе не нужно перебирать все его ключи и значения (`for key, value in firstValue.items(): if key == KEY`). Вместо этого достаточно:  `if KEY in firstValue`.

Строчка `data[firstKey] = firstValue` избыточна (до её выполнения уже `data[firstKey] is firstValue`).

Чтобы заменить значения во вложенных в `data` словарях на соответствующие значения из `library` словаря:

```
for d in data.values():
    for key in (library.keys() & d.keys()):
        d[key] = library[key]

# здесь в новый файл data сохраните
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/brython-dev/brython/3.4.0/www/src/brython.js"></script><body onload="brython()"><script type="text/python">
import json
from browser import document, html

@document["mybutton"].bind("click") 
def on_click(event):
    library = json.loads(document['library'].value)
    data = json.loads(document['data'].value)
    for d in data.values():
        for key in (library.keys() & d.keys()):
            d[key] = library[key]
    document['output'] <= html.PRE(json.dumps(data))
</script>
<label for="library">library: </label><textarea id="library" rows=12 cols=25> {
    "K1": "AAA",
    "K2": "BBB",
    "K3": "CCC",
    "K4": "DDD" 
 }</textarea><label for="data">data: </label><textarea id="data" rows=12 cols=25>{
   "First": 
    {
       "K1": 0, 
       "K2": [1,1,1,1],
       "K3": "QWERTY"
    },
   "Second":
    {
       "K4": 2
    }
}</textarea><div><button id="mybutton">Запустить</button></div><div id=output /></body>
```

Более универсальное решение показано [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/793580/23044). Если что-то не ясно, спрашивайте.