# Заполнить json файл случайными значениями на основе шаблона и заданных диапазонов для ключей

Tags: python, json

Существует два json файла, первый имеет вид:

```
{
   "First": 
   {
      "Key_1": 0,
      "Key_2": [1,34]
   }
}
```

второй имеет вид:

```
{
   "Key_1": [0,1],             
   "Key_2": [1,100]    
}
```

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы программа читала первый файл, брала "Key_1", находила его во втором файле, и принимала значения из диапазона, который задан во втором файле. В программе ниже приведен пример простого поиска ключей

```
path = Path('first.json')
P=Path('second.json')
data = json.loads(path.read_text(encoding='utf-8'))
Second=json.loads(P.read_text(encoding='utf-8'))
for KEY, VALUE in Second.items():
    for firstKey, firstValue in data.items():
        for key, value in firstValue.items():
```

я не знаю, как сделать так:

например, в первом файле берем "Key_1", смотрим, что его значение "0", значит и в новом, результирующем файле должна быть константа. Идем во второй файл, находим там "Key_1", видим, что значение у него- это диапазон "[0,1]", но по скольку в первом файле значение у "Key_1" константа, то надо выбрать константу из этого диапазона, либо 0, либо 1. Далее, берем "Key_2", видим, что в первом файле у него значение - это диапазон "[1,34]", значит и в новом, результирующем файле должен быть диапазон. Идем во второй файл, находим там "Key_2", видим, что значение у него- это диапазон "[1,100]", как сделать так, чтобы генерировался новый диапазон? Программа должна взять и с генерировать два новых числа из диапазона "[1,100]", первое число - это min, второе - это max, в результате должно быть что-то такое "[min,max]".

То есть программа должна понимать, что у нее в значениях в первом файле, константа или диапазон, и исходя из этого действовать

при этом, руками не вариант прописывать поля и значения

```
data_gen = {
   "frame":
   {
      "Key_1": lambda: randint(0, 1),
      "Key_2": lambda: [randint(1, 100) for i in range(2)]
   }
}
```

я мог бы прописать так, но мой json может состоять из тысячи строк, и руками все не прописать, надо как-то автоматизировать.

На уровне псевдокода я вижу как-то так

```
if(firstValue[value] == Const):
     firstValue[key] = random(VALUE)
if(firstValue[value] == [min,max]):
     new_min=random([min,max])
     new_max=random([min,max])
     firstValue[value] == [new_min,new_max]
```

И в результате должен получиться какой-то такой json

```
{
   "First": 
   {
      "Key_1": 1,
      "Key_2": [12,57]
   }
}
```

Comment: только целые и пары, не могу пока с ними разобраться

Comment: Не могу придумать, как все это делать, знаний синтаксиса не хватает

Answer (score 0):

Основная структура кода [так может выглядеть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/795478/23044):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json
from pathlib import Path

data = json.loads(Path('first.json').read_text(encoding='utf-8'))
library = json.loads(Path('second.json').read_text(encoding='utf-8'))
for d in data.values():
    for key in (library.keys() & d.keys()):
        d[key] = generate(d[key], library[key])

print(json.dumps(data))
```

где `generate()` функция создаёт новое значение:

```
def generate(current_value, possible_range):
    if isinstance(current_value, int):  # scalar
        return random.randint(*possible_range)
    else:  # range
        assert isinstance(current_value, list) and len(current_value) == 2
        return sorted(random.randint(*possible_range) for i in range(2))
```

Если больше типов, то можно на несколько функций разбить, к примеру, [используя `functools.singledispatch()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17101711/4279) или словарь с функциями (`funcs[type(v).__name__](*args)`) или `getattr()` на объекте по части имени метода в зависимости от типа (`getattr(builder, 'make_' + type(v).__name__)(*args)`), итд.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/brython-dev/brython/3.4.0/www/src/brython.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/brython-dev/brython/3.4.0/www/src/brython_stdlib.js"></script><body onload="brython()"><script type="text/python">
import json
import random

def generate(current_value, possible_range):
    if isinstance(current_value, int):
        return random.randint(*possible_range)
    else:
        assert isinstance(current_value, list) and len(current_value) == 2
        return sorted(random.randint(*possible_range) for i in range(2))

# try your own input
from browser import document, html
@document["mybutton"].bind("click") 
def on_click(event):
    library = json.loads(document['library'].value)
    data = json.loads(document['data'].value)
    for d in data.values():
        for key in (library.keys() & d.keys()):
            d[key] = generate(d[key], library[key])
    document['output'] <= html.PRE(json.dumps(data))
</script>
<label for="library">library: </label><textarea id="library" rows=12 cols=25>{
   "Key_1": [0,1],             
   "Key_2": [1,100]    
}</textarea><label for="data">data: </label><textarea id="data" rows=12 cols=25>{
   "First": 
   {
      "Key_1": 0,
      "Key_2": [1,34]
   }
}</textarea><button id="mybutton">Запустить</button><div id=output /></body>
```